# findByName() method returns null for gradle plugin task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using **maven-publis**h plugin. I have a publication called **myMedia**. When I try executing 
`tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository")`, it returns **null**. Why does it return null if there is a task by that name that maven-publish plugin created.

I'm not able to get around this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1 : START**

I tried Francisco Mateo's suggestion to use the afterEvaluate method, but this too didn't seem to work for me.

However, while trying to figure out the actual cause I came across one interesting observation. I found that the when I call  `tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository")` from within a task, then it works perfectly fine and prints out the task, i.e. **printTaskName** runs as expected :

```
task printTaskName{
   doLast{
println "task name found is :--- "+tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository")
   }
}
```

Now originally in my project's build.gradle I have a **publishSnapshot** task followed by ordering logic using **mustRunAfter** method:

```
task publishSnapshot (dependsOn: ['createMyMediaArchive','publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository'])
tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository").mustRunAfter tasks.findByName("createMyMediaArchive")
publishSnapshot.mustRunAfter tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository")
```

executing the **publishSnapshot** task gives below error:

```
Cannot invoke method mustRunAfter() on null object
```

**tasks.findByName** method doesn't seem to work here as it returns null.

Am I missing out on some basics?

**EDIT 1 : END**

**EDIT 2 : START**

The below build.gradle is an edited version of what I actually have. I am not allowed to share the script. But the script is identical in structure to what I have. The rest of build script is as it is as far as the structure and syntax is concerned, just the names changed. Gradle version is **3.5.1**

**build.gradle**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import Tasks.PublishArtifacts
import org.gradle.api.GradleException

buildscript {
       repositories {
          abcRelease() 
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
           classpath "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
           classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.10"
       }
}

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    abcSnapshot()
    xyzRelease()
 }

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin:'java'

apply from: "$rootDir/repositories.gradle"

def getMediaVersion(){
   project.mediaVersion
}

configurations{
    releaseMedia
}

 publishing{
      publications {
        myMedia(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId project.artifactId
            artifact "$project.artifactId"+"-"+getMediaVersion()+".tgz"
            version getMediaVersion()
        }
 }
         repositories project.artifactoryRepositories
 }

task publishSnapshot (dependsOn: ['createMyMediaArchive','publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository'])

tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository").mustRunAfter tasks.findByName("createMyMediaArchive")
publishSnapshot.mustRunAfter tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository")

afterEvaluate { evaluated -> 
    evaluated.tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository").configure {
        println "My Media name  ---------   "+it.name
    }
}

task printTaskName{
   doLast{
println "task name found is :--- "+tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository") // This returns task name as exected
   }
}

task createMyMediaArchive{
   doLast{
      //code for creating media
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

**EDIT 3: START**

If I run the tasks individually, i.e. first running task **createMyMediaArchive** and then running task **publishSnapshot** ,where the task**publishSnapshot** depends on
task **publishHelmMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository**, ie.

```
task publishSnapshot (dependsOn: ['publishHelmMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository'])
```

then both the tasks run successfully. This proves that gradle does have the task **publishHelmMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository** pre-configured. 
Also **gradlew tasks --all** prints out this task.

This behavior is making things look more confusing to me.

**EDIT 3 : END**

Comment: Check your spelling, this probably should be `SnapshotRepository`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that isn't the issue. it was a typo while writing this post. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have corrected the typo in the post

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the configuration performed by the `maven-publish` plugin is done lazily.

Wrapping in `afterEvaluate` should work.

```
afterEvaluate { evaluated -> 
    evaluated.tasks.findByName("publishMyMediaPublicationToSnapshotRepository").configure {
        println it.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. It still returns null. However, I have noticed one weird behavior. I'll update my OP with more details and further findings.

Comment: Please provide your full `build.gradle` file showing how you are configuring the `publishing` extension of the `maven-publish` plugin and specify the Gradle version you're using.

Comment: I have added the build.gradle code. Please do let me know in case I missed out on anything.

Comment: Please do let me know in case of any concerns